# How to upload a png image without recreating it in php

Tags: php, png

I have a script php who works to upload png files, but uploaded files loose some quality at rounded corners (and are uploaded at half of original size) and if I want to edit uploded png files later in fireworks it says unknow picture type or file.

Why do png uploded are not recognized by $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/x-png" ?
I was forced to use:

```
if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/png"){
```

if I didn't use it, the PNG picture won't upload.

My code is:

```
if ($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/x-png" || $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/png" || isset($_POST["nume_a_1"])){


$current_img=$_FILES['poza_a_1']['name'];
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($current_img, '.'), 1));

$new_image = str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($e_nume));
$nume = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $e_nume));
$id_poza = $e_id_poza;

$originalImage  = "../temps/".$new_image . "." . $extension;
$cale_poza  = "../img/".$new_image."." . $extension;


$action = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["poza_a_1"]['tmp_name'], $originalImage);

    //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poza_a']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile_o)) { 


//$max_upload_width = 1280;
//$max_upload_height = 900;
//$max_upload_width_th = 168;
//$max_upload_height_th = 130;

if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){
    $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage) ;
} 
if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/gif"){    
    $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);
}
if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/bmp"){    
    $image_source = imagecreatefromwbmp($originalImage);
}
if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/x-png"){
    $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
}
if($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["type"] == "image/png"){
    $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
}

imagealphablending( $image_source, true );


chmod($cale_poza,0777);

imagejpeg($image_source, $cale_poza,100);
chmod($cale_poza,0777);

//list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($cale_poza);
//  $new_width = $image_width;
//  $new_height = $image_height;
    //$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);
    //$image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($cale_poza);
    //imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    //$new_width, $new_height,
    //imagejpeg($new_image, $cale_poza, 100); // save

  //  imagedestroy($new_image);

    $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory

        $path_to_file = '../temps/';

        chdir($path_to_file);


        $originalImage_del = str_replace ("../temps/", "", $originalImage);
            unlink($originalImage_del);

        chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory
    }
```

OK, i resolved using move_uploaded_file and delete the rest of the code between ... :

```
$originalImage  = "../temps/".$new_image . "." . $extension;
$cale_poza  = "../img/".$new_image."." . $extension;
//$destination = "../img/".strtolower($e_nume).'/'.$new_image."-".$y."-".$e_id_poza."_th." . $extension;


//$action = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["poza_a_1"]['tmp_name'], $originalImage);



chmod($cale_poza,0777);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["poza_a_1"]["tmp_name"], $cale_poza);
```

Comment: OK, i resolved using move_uploaded_file:

Comment: FYI: `image/png` is the correct MIME type.